# python sort links in list

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have a list like this

```
list = [
    "https://google.com page 1",
    "https://example.com page 1",
    "https://example.com page 1",
    "https://example.com page 2",
    "https://google.com page 2",
    "https://google.com page 2",
    "https://google.com page 2",
    "https://example.com page 3",
    "https://google.com page 3"
]
```

the string looks like this "https://link.com page (number of page)"

the page after the link is tag i created so i can know from which page this link is

the number of page isn't on specific range
it's random

there is 3 links from page 1

and 3 links from page 2

i want to remove some links so it can match the smallest which is page 3

in this example smallest tag is page 3

basically remove 1 link that have page 1 and 2 links from page 2

how can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "smallest tag"? Do you mean the least frequent? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to be more explicit with your question. Right now it is ambiguous, which makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: Can you be more specific and show a less ambiguous example so that the Stackoverflow community help you @alsaibi

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i mean by tag the page (number) 

the string is "https://www.google.com page1"

Comment: @AvinashSingh 1 second i will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to keep the same number of strings in your list for each tag, where a tag is the immediate string after your url:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = ["https://google.com page 1","https://example.com page 1",
        "https://example.com page 1","https://example.com page 2","https://google.com page 2",
        "https://google.com page 2","https://google.com page 2","https://example.com page 3",
        "https://google.com page 3"]

d = defaultdict(list)
for e in my_list:
    url, tag = e.split(maxsplit=1)
    d[tag].append(url)

min_freq = min(map(len, d.values()))

my_list = [' '.join([url, tag]) for tag, l in d.items() for url in l[:min_freq]]
my_list
```

output:

```
['https://google.com page 1',
 'https://example.com page 1',
 'https://example.com page 2',
 'https://google.com page 2',
 'https://example.com page 3',
 'https://google.com page 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get notice about your variable name, you call it "list", I don't recommend call the variable by only their types.

I understood that you want to create a list without duplicates, then, here you go:

```
first_list = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
new_no_duplicates_list = []

for value in first_list:
    if value not in new_no_duplicates_list:
       new_no_duplicates.append(value)
```

This loop is appending new value to list if the list not containing that value, that means if there's already a value it'll not append it twice.

The output of the code: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: i'm sorry that i can't explain it right

but i want to remove the extra links

not duplicates

there is 2 links that end with page 3

i want all links in page 1 and page 2 to be the same length as page 3